# BeautifulSoup: How to parse an un-id'ed list of TDs in table

Tags: python, html-table, beautifulsoup

Using bs4 I'm able to use soup.find_all() to find each of the s for the table. HTML is below.

However, how do I efficiently access specific columns within each ? Say I only want the 1st, 3rd and 5th column.

In other words, is there a way to so something similar to "date = row.td[1]" or "price_low = row.td[3]" etc?

Thanks.

```
<tr class="cmc-table-row" style="display:table-row">
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--sticky cmc-table__cell--left">
        <div class="">Dec 23, 2019</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,508.90</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,656.18</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,326.19</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,355.63</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">27,831,788,041</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">133,275,709,111</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the way you mentioned? After all of the `td` elements are in a list, using indexing should work just fine as you have already written.

Comment: You could use pandas to get the entire table, then just select the specific columns from that dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tr class="cmc-table-row" style="display:table-row">
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--sticky cmc-table__cell--left">
        <div class="">Dec 23, 2019</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,508.90</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,656.18</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,326.19</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">7,355.63</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">27,831,788,041</div>
    </td>
    <td class="cmc-table__cell cmc-table__cell--right">
        <div class="">133,275,709,111</div>
    </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': ''})[0:5:2]:
    print(item.text)
```

output:

```
Dec 23, 2019
7,656.18
7,355.63
```